# POST route doesn't work after Laravel Vue deploy on Ubuntu server

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, ubuntu, axios

After deploying my Laravel app on Ubuntu server the broken POST no longer works, despite the migrations being successful
Here are the reference files

```
web.php
// Submit route
Route::post('/submit', [HomeController::class, 'submit'])->name('submit');

VueComponent
 submit() {
            if (this.loaded) {
                this.loaded = false;
                this.success = false;
                this.errors = {};
                axios.post('/submit', this.fields).then(response => {
                    this.fields = {}; //Clear input fields.
                    this.loaded = true;
                    this.success = true;
                    this.goToHome();
                }).catch(error => {
                    this.loaded = true;
                    if (error.response.status === 422) {
                        this.errors = error.response.data.errors || {};
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

,

/etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://162.19.27.126
ServerAdmin ubuntu@162.19.27.126
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/WinCond/public
<Directory /var/www/html/WinCond>
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

error request

Richiedi URL: http://162.19.27.126/submit
Metodo di richiesta: POST
Codice di stato: 500 Internal Server Error
Indirizzo remoto: 162.19.27.126:80
Norme sui referrer: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

The route appears in php artisan route: list

Apache access.log

151.57.85.190 - - [30/Apr/2022:20:13:41 +0000] "POST /submit HTTP/1.1" 500 1144 "http://162.19.27.126/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"

Comment: It might be a problem with `nginx` server config or your web server

Comment: the error means that your `HTTP` version is not supported form some reason

Comment: I use apache now I update the question by posting the configuration code

Comment: Check the log file in ```${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log```

Comment: 151.57.85.190 - - [30/Apr/2022:20:13:41 +0000] "POST /submit HTTP/1.1" 500 1144 "http://162.19.27.126/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"

Comment: this is access.log in error.log 
I have nothing in reference

Answer (score 1):

make sure you HTTP server allowed POST method, do you have check it?

Comment: Forgive the ignorance but we have been planning for less than a year, where do I check?

Comment: Where is hosted? You can ask your Ubuntu server administrator to allowed post method on server? But if not work, can you check php.ini, then try to increase sice at post_max_size